# Scrapy: pagination with post request doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, http-post

I am trying to extract from this website: https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/ 
The spider works without any errors but it doesn't do the pagination that I am passing with the payload. I only get back the same page. 
I have tried to use the json library to configure my payload, however the payload itself is not in json.
Please help.

```
import scrapy

class MrlodgeSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mrlodge_spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        for pageNumber in range(1,10):
            s = """mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bdate_from%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brent_from%5D=1000&mr\
                l_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brent_to%5D=8500&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bpersons%5D=1&mrl_ft%5Bfd\
                %5D%5Bkids%5D=0&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brooms_from%5D=1&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brooms_to\
                %5D=9&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Barea_from%5D=20&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Barea_to%5D=480&\
                mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bsterm%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bradius%5D=50&mrl_ft%5Bfd\
                %5D%5Bmvv%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bobjecttype_cb%5D%5B%5D=w&mrl_ft%5B\
                fd%5D%5Bobjecttype_cb%5D%5B%5D=h&mrl_ft%5Bpage%5D={}""".format(pageNumber)
            payload = '{'+s+'}'
            print(payload)
            yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/', method='POST',
                                body=payload, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})


    def parse(self, response):
        for apartment in response.xpath("//div[@class='mrl-ft-results mrlobject-list']/div"):
            yield {
                'info': apartment.xpath(".//div[@class='obj-smallinfo']/text()").get()
                 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `callback=parse` to the `Request` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach worked for me.

```
import json

headers = {
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'https://www.mrlodge.de',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/',
}

data = [
  ('mrl_ft[fd][date_from]', ''),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][rent_from]', '900'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][rent_to]', '8500'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][persons]', '1'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][kids]', '0'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][rooms_from]', '1'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][rooms_to]', '9'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][area_from]', '20'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][area_to]', '480'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][sterm]', ''),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][radius]', '50'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][mvv]', ''),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][objecttype_cb][]', 'w'),
  ('mrl_ft[fd][objecttype_cb][]', 'h'),
  ('mrl_ft[page]', '2'),
]

yield Request(url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=json.dumps(data))
```

You'll have to set some of the values in the data dynamically of course - such as the mrl_ft[page] - to go through all pages.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the headers are wrong and incomplete. I see that the headers are the following:

```
Host: www.mrlodge.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 468
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: fe_typo_user=cbf861eb412b7182ccf72aa5ca87c932; uac=true
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

`Content-Type` is also different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately changing the headers didn't help. Do you have another idea?